# Xcode 5 Developing for OS X 10.6

Tags: cocoa, xcode5

I have 10.9/Xcode 5 and I'm trying to write a Cocoa app for Snow Leopard. I deactivated auto layout and set the deployment target to 10.6, but the archived application won't launch on 10.6 because it can't load the nib (console output). From what I've read, I need to use garbage collection instead of ARC. If this is true, how to I modify my project to build and run for 10.6? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure the XIB itself is configured to build for 10.6. In the right-hand pane of Interface Builder, you should see this:

[image]

If you're targeting 64-bit 10.6, then you can use ARCLite, which is just fine and I strongly recommend it. The only thing you really give up is auto-zeroing weak references. You only have to give up ARC if you go 32-bit. I recommend sicking to 64-bit if you can possibly help it. You give up a lot if you target 32-bit. To use ARCLite, you don't have to change anything. It's automatically selected when you compile an ARC program for 10.6.

As a note: yes, what you're doing is totally possible. I still target 10.5 with a 10.9/Xcode5 setup.

Comment: Note we found a bad crasher when we targeted 10.5 with Xcode 5. For some customers they’d crash in thread 5 in an Apple function called, like, BUF_MEM_GROW(). This crash only appeared on 10.5 machines and had never appeared in the 5 years before with this app. This was on 32-bit, non-ARC.

Comment: I don't know off of the top of my head if the machine I'm targeting is 64- or 32-bit, but since I already went through the steps you listed above and it didn't work, I'm guessing that it is 32-bit. How would I convert my project to support this? I started developing when ARC was introduced, so I haven't done it any other way before.

Comment: Converting to manual memory management just requires turning off "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" in the build settings. But you will need to learn manual memory management. ocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html But do double-check that you're on a 32-bit machine. When you say "it didn't work," do you mean specifically that it complained that it could not find ARClite? There are many things covered by "it didn't work."